# How To handle offline case for fetch API call : ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, fetch

How to handle api call using fetch when device is offline,

```
try {
  fetch("https://api.com/books", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      ToastAndroid.show("TEST API called response", 5000)

      response.json().then((data) => {
        ToastAndroid.show("TEST API called SUCCESS", 5000)
        console.log(data.places.length)
      })
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      ToastAndroid.show("TEST API called failed", 5000)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      ToastAndroid.show("TEST API called finally", 5000)

    })
} catch (e) {
  ToastAndroid.show("TEST API called network failed", 5000)
}
```

when I run this code, and the device is offline, then no toast is being shown, so my question is how to handle this case, the execution of the above code is not going inside catch nor finally, please suggest what I'm doing wrong here. thank you